# How to return first operand if the second operand of + operator overloading is zero in C++?

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

I have this class definition:

```
class foo{

public:
    foo();
    foo(const int& var);
    foo(const foo& var);
    ~foo();

    const foo operator +(const foo& secondOp) const;

private:
    int a;
    //plus other values, pointers, e.t.c.

};
```

Also I have made this implementation for '+' operator overloading:

```
const foo foo::operator +(const foo& secondOp) const{

    //I want here to check if i have one operand or two...
    if ((FIRST_OPERAND.a!=0) && (secondOp.a==0)){
        cout << "ERROR, second operand is zero";
        return FIRST_OPERAND;
    }
    else if ((FIRST_OPERAND.a==0) && (secondOp.a!=0)){
        cout << "ERROR, first operand is zero";
        return secondOp;
    }

}
```

When i write in `main()`:

```
foo a(2);
foo b;
foo c;

//I want here to print the ERROR and
//return only the values of a
c = a + b;
```

1. Ηow can i `return` the value of the first operand if the second operand is zero and vice versa?

Comment: Have `operator+` return an object of some arbitrary type with the relevant information and overload `operator=` for that type only.

Comment: If the second operand is missing, your code would look something like `c = a + ;`, right?  That simply won't compile.

Comment: Can you be more specific? With a code-example? @0x499602D2

Comment: The second operand to `operator+()` will never be missing. It is never involved in the expression `c = a;`. In this case the default generated assignment will be used.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth sorry, i didn't mean that!! Let me correct it...

Comment: As a comment never make `+` operator overload as member function, make it as a non-member friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Since it's a member function, the first operand is `*this`, so replace `FIRST_OPERAND.a` with `this->a` or just `a`.

However, it might be better to make it a non-member function to allow conversions on both operands (i.e. to be able to write `a + 2` or `2 + a`). It will need to be a friend in order to access the private member(s).

```
friend foo operator +(const foo& firstOp, const foo& secondOp);
```

Also, it's best not to return a `const` value as that prevents moving from the return value.

Answer (score 0):

It is the compiler that checks the syntaxical correctness of the program. It is unable to distinguish whether you indeed wanted to write

```
c = a;
```

that is to do the assignment or you wanted to write

```
c = a + b;
```

The both statements are correct.

It is a so-called logical error. The compiler is unable to see what we thoght.

Answer (score 0):

For your line `c = a;` The assignment operator is implemented by the compiler (just shallow copying the object memory).
That is the reason your code compiles "without the second operand".

If you wish to disallow using the assignment operator - hide it. E.g. by implementing with the `private` access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define this function as a friend function
`friend Int operator + (int first, Int &second);`
this function can perform obj + 2 or 2 + obj.

```
Int operator + (int first, Int& second){
    second.a += first;
    return second;
}
```